# d3js How to gather nodes by cluster un force layout?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have network and each node has a property group obtained by a clustering method. I would like to know what is the best method to render a network with the force layout where nodes belonging to the same group are gathered in space?

One way, but i don't know how to implement it, would be to add a attractive force between nodes of the same group (little compared to the repulsive force applied to all nodes).

Answer (score 4):

one possibility is to devide space in `nb_group` directions and push nodes in the direction allocated to their group:

```
   var angle = 2*Math.PI/nb_group;
   var intensity = 500;

    var updateNode = function() {
    this.attr("transform", function(d) {
        var xm = d.x + intensity*Math.cos(angle*d.group);
        var ym = d.y + intensity*Math.sin(angle*d.group);
        return "translate(" + xm + "," + ym + ")";
    });
    }
```

my `intensity` is hugh because I have charge of 1000
[image]